# Linear address and physical address

Tags: memory-management, x86, memory-address, memory-segmentation, address-space

What is linear address? How is it different from physical address?

Comment: related: [How are segment registers involved in memory address translation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52222133) / [What is the difference between linear ,physical ,logical and virtual memory address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62997536)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Linear address is generated <s>after</s> **before** page
table mapping.  Physical addres is
generated <s>before</s> **after** page table mapping(ie
paging).

Linear Adress,created by adding
logical address to the base of
segment, CS,DS,ES,SS,FSor GS.

When Paging is enabled, the page
tables are used to translate linear
address to physical address.

On the Other Hand, Physical Address is
nothing but, the address value that
appears on pins of processor during a
memory read/memory write operations.

InShort, we can say if paging is
disabled linear address = physical
address

Comment: can you elaborate your answer

Answer (score 12):

The Linear Address is the virtual Address; the address a process uses (pre-translated). The physical address is the post-translated address, its an address of some page in physical memory.

Note that Sankar's answer

> Linear address is generated after page table mapping. Physical addres is generated before page table mapping(ie paging).

<s>is</s> was wrong, he <s>has</s> had these backwards (fixed now). The Linear Address is before the page table mapping, and the physical address is the address that comes from the page table mapping.